# Como criar um vetor que exibe a frequência de cada elemento em uma matriz?

Tags: java, matriz, método, array

"Escreva um método **contaFrequencia** que recebe dados de uma matriz A que possui inteiros entre 0 e x; gera um vetor com as ocorrências de cada inteiro entre 0 e x. Escreva um método **maior** que recebe um vetor de inteiros e devolve o maior elemento do vetor. Escreva o módulo main, que preenche uma matriz somente com valores entre 0 e x e exibe qual valor foi o mais frequente (chame obrigatoriamente os métodos **contaFrequencia**, **maior** e **leMatriz**). "

Eu já montei a matriz sorteando os números, agora estou tentando criar o método **contaFrequencia**. Tenho duas dúvidas:

1) Como faço pra que o algoritmo "pule" a contagem de números que já foram contados? Por exemplo, se a matriz for: (0   0   1); (2   3   0); (1   2   3), o programa vai contar 0 três vezes, aí quando passar pro próximo, vai contar 0 três vezes outra vez.

2) Como declarar o vetor que vai armazenar as frequências contadas sem saber seu tamanho? Pensei em criar uma string e depois convertê-la para vetor de inteiros, mas a repetição na contagem da frequência ainda seria um problema. Também pensei em deixar os elementos da matriz em ordem crescente para encontrar o maior valor. Com isso eu saberia o tamanho do vetor que armazena as frequências. Mas não estou conseguindo ordenar utilizando Arrays.sort()...

```
public class Freq_Maior {
    static Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Digite o número de linhas e colunas da matriz: ");
        int m = ent.nextInt();
        int n = ent.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Digite o valor máximo do intervalo usado para preencher a matriz: ");
        int x = ent.nextInt();
        int [][] A = new int[m][n];
        leMatrizR(A, x);

    }
    // método para ler a matriz
    public static void leMatrizR(int matriz[][], int a) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<matriz[0].length; j++) {               
                matriz[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(a+1);
            }
        }
    } 
    public static void Freq(int matriz[][]) {
        ????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu vetor com as frequências você na verdade sabe o tamanho: `x + 1`, sendo `x` o valor máximo do intervalo usado para preencher a matriz. Então o vetor `freqs` pode ser declarado como:

```
int [] freqs = new int[x + 1];
```

Feito isso, você pode passá-lo para o método `Freq` e realizar a computação das frequências, e para "pular" os elementos ja contados, basta compará-los com o elemento que estamos querendo contar no momento:

```
public static void contaFrequencia(int matriz[][], int freqs[]) {
    // para cada elemento possível (0..x)...
    for ( int e = 0; e < freqs.length; e++ ) {
        freqs[e] = 0; // initializa o valor da frequência com 0.
        for ( int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++ ) {
                // se encontramos o elemento...
                if ( matriz[i][j] == e ) {
                    // incrementamos a frequência do elemento.
                    freqs[e]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas como faço essa comparação dos elementos já contados com o que estou contando no momento?
O programa também está imprimindo os valores do vetor, mas eu não mandei imprimir... estranho.

Comment: O primeiro `for` varia a variável `e` para todos os valores possíveis de elemento, garantindo que a gente verifique todos eles. Depois, no `if ( matriz[i][j] == e )`, verificamos se o elemento atual da matriz é o que estamos contando. Apenas no caso de ele ser o elemento sendo contato, incrementamos a posição respectiva desse elemento no vetor de frequência. Gostaria de notar que o algorítmo que implementei é ineficiente, e é possível reimplementá-lo realizando apenas uma passagem na matriz inteira.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda! Acabei encontrando um outro jeito de fazer baseada na sua sugestão.